# Accessing Firebase list values with Angular 2 and AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

So far I've been able to migrate my CRUD app to Firebase. I can list, create and delete news. I'm struggling with edit though.

This is the edit component. It takes a snapshot of the route params which is equal to the $key value of that particular news in Firebase. Then I concatenate it to the database listing:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-edit-news',
  templateUrl: 'edit-news.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['edit-news.component.css']
})
export class EditNewsComponent {
  noticia: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private af: AngularFire) { 
      this.news = af.database.list('news/'+this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
    }

}
```

I'm new to observables but I thought with this I could be able to access the concrete object of the database using interpolation such us `{{news.title}}` Obviously, I'm wrong. Any help?

Comment: Could you please provide the part of your template where you are using news observable? I have a feeling that you haven't added async pipe to your ngfor call. For example *ngFor="let item of items | async"

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets There's no iteration for this one. It's just a form that takes several news values from the database inside inputs with `[(ngModel)]="news.foo"` and you can edit them and save the changes. The interpolation I mentioned was just an example of accessing the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the html template for EditNewsComponent use

```
{{(news | async)?.title}}    // you don't need '?' if it can't be null
```

Probably also you need to change

```
this.news = af.database.list('news/'+this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
```

to

```
this.news = af.database.object('news/'+this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
```

so that you are accessing an object and not a list.

Comment: Yeah... I changed it to object. My mistake. But the problem is still there. How do you bind those object values to input nodes with `[(ngModel)]` instead of using interpolation syntax? I need to be able to edit and save the existing news after all. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax

```
noticia: firebaseListObservable<any[]>;
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,public af:AngularFireAuth) {
     this.noticia = db.list('/news',{
       query: {
          orderByChild:'id'
              }
     });
   }
```